# Combine picture with text and save to disc. (Someecards style)

Tags: javascript, html, image, image-processing, save

I need to create around 200 **JPG** files that are similar to someecards:

They consist of:

> - background JPG
> - PNG layer in one corner with 1 to 5 stars
> - String of text that needs to fit into specific area.

I need to batch create files that combine the 3 elements into one JPG

I have CSV file with filename, stars, "text"

Example: review07,3,"This is average, but pay attention to xxx and yyy"

How to combine above elements int one JPG file?

Answer (score 0):

use the following code to draw an image over another one:

```
using (Graphics grfx = Graphics.FromImage(image))
{
    grfx.DrawImage(newImage, x, y)
}
```

and you can use the following piece of code to write text over image:

```
using(Graphics grfx = Graphics.FromImage(image))
{
    using (Font arialFont =  new Font("Arial", 10))
    {
        grfx.DrawString("Your Text", arialFont, Brushes.Blue, new PointF(10f, 10f));
    }
}
```